# Visual Studio 2015 entire solution search; ignore folder

Tags: visual-studio

This has been bugging me for a while; does anybody know when you do a full solution search ( ctrl + shift + F ) how you can exclude a certain folder(s)?

The reason I ask is because in our project we have a folder with kendo js files which are huge and Visual Studio includes these files in its search which causes Visual Studio to crash a lot of times.

PS; I had this in VS 2013, but since a week I'm using VS 2015 and I'm experiencing the same issue.

There are older posts that date from 2009 stating there is no real solution unless you exclude folders from your solution. I wonder if there still is no solution in VS 2015 for this.

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell Visual Studio to exclude folders from the Find in Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607069/how-do-i-tell-visual-studio-to-exclude-folders-from-the-find-in-files)

Comment: See also: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7757844-setting-to-ignore-folders-in-the-editor

Comment: Thanks Cody, seems like that is the answer I was looking for. However I can't seem to mark your reply as the answer.

Comment: Well, it wasn't an answer, it was a comment. If you think this question is a duplicate, you should be able to close it as such yourself.

Comment: @Yannick What was the solution please?. The link from Cody does not work anymore.

Comment: The link provided an alternative workaround, because it isn't possible. I can't remember exactly as I did not use it, but I believe they excluded the folder with the big scripts from their project.

Comment: I found that using the MSBuild exclusion property is working fine to exclude from global find in Visual studio 2017.. For core projects in Visual Studio 2017 I add the folders to exclude to the project files (.csproj) <DefaultItemExcludes> property .. : e.g. **<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);wwwroot\**</DefaultItemExcludes>**