# How to stop Visual Studio 2019 with CMake and GIT from searching .git directory

Tags: git, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to use the CMake and GIT support in Visual Studio, the way it is described here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/

In particular there is no .sln file listing all of the source in the solution; instead there is a tree that Visual Studio is auto-crawling.

One thing that is trouble is the Find All in Solution. VS is searching the hidden .git local repository. Obviously I only want to search the non hidden source.

Is there a trick to make Find All work as I expect?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036168/6309 (and other answers in that page) help?

Comment: That specific answer refers to C# solution file which is not relevant. The other suggestion there is to manually construct a search path. I figured since this scenario is so ubiquitous there might be a proper method for Find All in Solution that does not involve effort of building a complex search path.