# How can I exclude these folders and files when searching a very large Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, findinfiles

I am trying to search a very large application with hundreds of folders and thousands of files using the Visual Studio "Find in files" feature.  I want to search all C# files (`*.cs`) excluding:

- `View*.cs`
- `*\UnitTests\*.cs`
- `*\Archive\*.cs`

I found [How do I tell Visual Studio to exclude folders from the Find in Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607069/how-do-i-tell-visual-studio-to-exclude-folders-from-the-find-in-files) and responses, but due to the size of the application, adding each folder is not workable, nor is unchecking "Search subfolders":

New folders are added frequently so I'd rather have an exclude list instead of an include list so I don't miss anything.

Is there a "Not" operator syntax for file types?  I tried `^`, `!`, and `|` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> which will give you following option.

In the search window you can select which folders to include in the search.

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively if you have [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win) installed and if your project is a git repo then easiest way is to use following command. I tested it with my project and it works fine with sub folders as well.

```sh
git ls-files -- '*.cs' ':!:*Test*.cs'
```

This will include `*.cs` file but exclude anything like `*Test*.cs`. You can change the pattern as per your requirement.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing.  However, there are hundreds of subfolders.  I want to skip all the unit tests and view files that are in the subfolders without explicitly selecting the hundreds of folders I do want to search. If someone adds a new folder to a solution I have to know that and manually update my folder set to search.

Comment: do you have git cli installed and is your project git repo? check the updated answer.

Comment: No on git, using VSTS exclusively.

Comment: you can still utilize the gibash functionality, just download a git bash and try `git init` command in your projects root directory and use above command to list the required files