How can I hide the "dist" and "coverage" folders in Visual Studio 2022?
For some reason, Visual Studio won't let me hide the "dist" and "coverage" folders. I've tried everything I can think ofbut they're still there. They're basically dead weight to me, as they just choke up my searches; when I need to find them and see what's going on, I know where they are. I just don't want Visual Studio showing them to me all the time.
"Exclude from project" is one of the first things I tried - it added the expected  items to the .esproj file, but Visual Studio ignores them and keeps showing the files anyway.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78973546/how-can-i-hide-the-dist-and-coverage-folders-in-visual-studio-2022 might be what you are looking for?

@TimothyG. that's a link back to this question?

oops! Not sure how I did that - meant this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607069/how-can-i-tell-visual-studio-to-exclude-folders-from-the-find-in-files

If the  “dist" and "coverage" folders are not need in build, you can consider to use "Exclude From Project" via right clicking the folder in Solution Explorer.

One of the first things I tried was "exclude from project", and that adds the expected exclusions to the .esproj file as usual, but Visual Studio seems to be completely ignoring it.

Did you toggle "Show All files"? If you toggle it, the excluded files should not be displayed.

Toggling "show all files" adds in the ".angular", ".vscode", "node_modules" and "obj" folders, in the same way as I'd expect any other Visual Studio project to add in the "bin" and "obj" directories. Usually they're not visible, as I usually don't have "show all files" switched on.


How can I hide the "dist" and "coverage" folders in Visual Studio 2022?

I think there is no built-in method/menu/command to hide folders in Solution Explorer and  it's a new feature. Therefore， i would suggest you raise a feature request at Visual Studio Forum.
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
Besides, i found this similar ticket Folder with only Visible="False" items still appears in Solution Explorer.
As a workaround, you can hide content files under a folder except the folder itself.
<None Include="Folder/**" Visible="False" />


Just tried this and it makes no difference, I'm afraid. I will leave feedback and see if they can fix this because it makes things very much more difficult to work with.

Okay, looks like this problem return in VS2022, you can also report this issue at Visual Studio Forum

This looks like the same issue except in my case VS isn't even hiding any of the files in the folder.

Folder with Visible="False" can hide any of files in the folder at my side. Did you add <ItemGroup>  <None Include="dist/**" Visible="False" /> </ItemGroup> in your .esproj file ? Please double check the folder path and make sure it is correct.

Yes, I just tried it again, they weren't in an ItemGroup to begin with but I added that, saved the project file, then closed Visual Studio and reopened it. It had no effect.

Could you share a sample of your project file with us to check?

Here it is:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.45-alpha">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupCommand>npm start</StartupCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>`
...deleted...
    <Folder Include="src\styles\pages\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="dist/**" Visible="False" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="dist/**" Visible="False" />
  </ItemGroup>
    </Project>


Sorry can't seem to get the code formatting to work in that comment

Looks like you are using the version 0.5.45-alpha of Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk. Will it work if you use the latest version 1.0.1738743?

Yes, that solved it! Finally, thanks. I had to remove the excludes I did above and then exclude through the UI but it finally works!

Greate! Meanwhile you can report this issue "Parent folder of items marked as Visible=False still show up in solution explorer" at Visual Studio Forum to get further assistance.
